# Check if input string exceeds buffer limit (crash)

Tags: c, string, memory, buffer

I'm creating a function that will pass a directory path as an argument or if it is left blank, prompt the user for an input.

I have set my `PATH_MAX=100` and `if` statements to check `if ((strlen(folder path) + strlen(file path)) >  PATH_MAX)` will ask the user to input again.

However when I was checking that all conditions work (set `PATH_MAX=20`), if `folder path` exceeds by itself the `PATH_MAX`, buffer crashes due to insufficient size (`L'Buffer is too small' &&0`).

Is there a way to check whether the user exceeds the `PATH_MAX` beforehand and inform that path is too long, in order to avoid crashing the buffer? Or should i just increase the size of `PATH_MAX`?

**Code:**

```
#define PATH_MAX 100
void CreateFiles(char folder[PATH_MAX])
{
    char addrbook[PATH_MAX] = "caf-sorted.txt";
    char path[PATH_MAX]="";

    if ((strlen(folder)<4)) 
    {
        //User inputs directory
        printf("Enter New Directory\n(!Do not enter filename!)\n");

        if (NULL == fgets(path, sizeof path, stdin))
        {//check if fgets fails
            if (ferror(stdin))
            {
                folder="";
                perror("fgets() failed");
                CreateFiles(folder);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        memcpy(path, folder, strlen(folder));

    path[strcspn(path, "\n\r")] = 0;

    if (strlen(addrbook) > 0 && '\\' != path[strlen(path) - 1])
    {
        if (PATH_MAX < strlen(path))
        {
            errno = EINVAL;
            perror("'path' too long");
            folder="";
            CreateFiles(folder);
            return;
        }

        strcat(path, "\\");
    }

    if (PATH_MAX < (strlen(path) + strlen(addrbook)))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        perror("'path\\filename' too long");
        folder="";
        CreateFiles(folder);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check it in the place where you are getting it from.

Comment: Even with `CreateFiles(char folder[PATH_MAX])`, `folder` could pointer to a string longer than `MAX_PATH` - this can fail `memcpy(path, folder, strlen(folder));`.

Comment: `folder` is being checked in main before passing in `CreateFiles`, `if (folder>PATH_MAX){folder="";}`

Comment: `path[strlen(path) - 1]` is an exploitable hack as `strlen(path)` is not guaranteed to be > 0.

Comment: `if (folder>PATH_MAX)` compares a pointer to an integer - perhaps you meant some other test?  IAC, better that `CreateFiles()` stands on its own and does not fail should a  pointer to a long string get passed in.

Comment: yeah I meant `(strlen(folder)>PATH_MAX`. The `folder` argument is based on the `argv[1]` from `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: `path[strcspn(path, "\n\r")] = 0;` is odd.  The only following use of `path[]` is `path[strlen(path) - 1]`.  Is this codes intent, to copy `folder` to `path` and only check the last character?

Comment: the `path[strcspn(path, "\n\r")] = 0;` is there to catch the `\n` and remove it, otherwise the `folder` and the `file` when combined would include a `\n` in the middle

Comment: Excuse me, I missed the `strcat(path, "\\");`

Comment: *where `file` is `addrbook`, later on the code I use the `folder` and `addrbook` to create a path for the `caf-sorted.txt` file

Comment: A simpler approach would be `int len = snprintf(new_path, sizeof new_path, "%s%s%s", left_side, slash, right_size); if (len < 0 || len >= sizeof new_path) Handle_NoRoom();`

Comment: @chux `'snprintf': identifier not found`. Seen in documentation that it is included in `<stdio.h>` but seems not to.

Comment: @D.A What compiler/version/computer are you using?

Comment: @chux visual studio 2010, and company's builder doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the terminating null character into account

```
if (!(strlen(path) < PATH_MAX))
```

makes sure that the count of characters in path (without the null character) is always at least one less than PATH_MAX, which leaves space for the terminating null character.

You have to take that into account with every C string you use, since strlen(char *string) is always one LESS than the space you need to store the string if you want to be able to null-terminate it.

Edit: So I've looked into at least the first few lines of your function and tried to re-implement them quickly. It's not beautiful, but it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define PATH_MAX 100

void create_files (char *folder)
{
    char addr_book[] = "caf-sorted.txt";
    char path[PATH_MAX];


    // Setting all bytes in *path to zero
    bzero(path, PATH_MAX);



    // If the folder name is too short, we ask for a new one
    if (strlen(folder) < 4) {

        char c; // This will store our input from stdin, one char at a time



        // As long as the supplied path name is too short, we'll keep asking:

        while (strlen(path) < 4) {
            printf("Please enter a path (no filename!): ");


            // We get one character at a time from stdin using getc(...):
            // until we encounter a newline

            for (int i = 0; (c = getc(stdin)) != '\n'; i++) {

                if (i < PATH_MAX - 1) {

                    // As long as we have space for two more characters
                    // (the value of c plus a null character after it)
                    // We'll keep appending c:

                    path[i] = c;

                } else if (i == PATH_MAX - 1) {

                    // If we get too many characters from stdin, we
                    // display an error message and reset our path to
                    // all null characters again, so the outermost loop
                    // will run again

                    fprintf(stderr, "Path is too long!\n");
                    bzero(path, PATH_MAX);

                    // Notice that we do not have a break statement
                    // here, we iterate through the input string from
                    // stdin until we encounter a newline character,
                    // so we don't have any superfluous characters
                    // that spill into the beginning ouf our freshly
                    // reset path string
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Or, you know, if the programmer specifies a proper value,
        // Just do it the easy way and copy that into our path string
        // (although this will truncate a folder name that is too long):

        strncpy(path, folder, PATH_MAX - 1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    create_files("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the buffer crashes in the fgets command. If it was passed that stage my `if` statements would have captured it. So basically I have to find a way so that fgets doesn't exceed the limit

Comment: `fgets(path, PATH_MAX, stdin);`

Same principle. You might want to set all the bytes in path to zero first, like this:

`bzero(path, PATH_MAX)`

for this you'll need to

`#include <strings.h>`

Comment: So the best approach would be limiting `fgets` to accept 99 characters? I new that, but imagined there would be a better approach. `string.h` is already included. Couldn't write down every line, there are too many:)

Comment: This might be confusing, because there is <string.h> (singular) and <strings.h> (plural). This is how it is on my system, anyways. And I just looked at the fgets(...) man page, it already seems to read size - 1 bytes. I'll dig into the code and see what I can find.

Comment: @afdggfh "You might want to set all the bytes in path to zero first" --> OP's code all ready does that with `char path[PATH_MAX]="";`

Comment: Does this do all the bytes or just the first one though? I'm not sure.

Comment: Object initialization is all or nothing, never partial.  The remainder gets filled too - in this case with zeros.

Comment: @D.A this answer is on the right track. `if (PATH_MAX < (strlen(path) + strlen(addrbook)))` should be `if (PATH_MAX <= (strlen(path) + strlen(addrbook)))` and similar `<` --> `<=` changes elsewhere.

Comment: @chux Ok, I get that and will change that but the main problem is not checking after if it's longer, it is during typing. It's after fgets that buffer crashes on input. I will check limiting fgets as afdggfh suggested

Comment: Yeah, I've been fiddling with your code, I think there might be a couple of issues. Hang on.

Comment: @D.A The `fgets()` should _not_ use `char path[PATH_MAX]`.  1) `fgets()` typically saves a `'\n'`, so `char path[PATH_MAX+1]` is better.  2) There is no need to strongly limit user input.  Use `char path[2*PATH_MAX]`.  _then_ analyze user input for excessiveness.

Comment: just be careful, this is not the entire code, it's just part of it. Limiting fgets got me the path too long I wanted but also gets some extra `\n` that make the code run twice before I can input again

Comment: @chux That's one way to do it. I will try some things around and post an update when I get it resolved. If you'd be kind, both of you, give an upvote. Thanks for everything

Comment: @chux `fgets(path, PATH_MAX, stdin);` is not correct. Cause let's say that `PATH_MAX=10` and your input is 40 characters long. What it does is split the input into 4 of 10 characters. So for example the input `D:\folderrrr\subfolder\anotherfolder` would be 1)`D:\folderr`, 2)`rr\subfold`, 3)`er\another`, 4)`folder`. This will check every one of them like it is 4 different inputs

Comment: @D.A Not quite.  1) I did not suggesting `fgets(path, PATH_MAX, stdin);` 2) `fgets(path, 10, stdin)` will save up to 9 characters of user input, not 10. `fgets()` appends a null character.  3) I would use `char path[2*PATH_MAX]; fgets(path, sizeof path, stdin);`  Any input filling `path[]` without a `'\n'` would be considered excessively hostile and error out the code.  The other somewhat long input that would get a warning and a retry.

Comment: @chux I know you didn't suggest it, I just wanted to include you in the comment. Actually it does what I said in the previous comment. I used the debugger and took it step by step, watching the value of `input` going from 1 to 4 as above. It is like using it in a loop as long as there are characters left. I will just increase the size. A way to do it as my original question suggested is to capture every single character and use a counter. But the easy solution is to increase the array size